# C# Reading continuous data from serial port every 1 minute

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, serial-port, serial-communication

Currently I've been working on an Automated Guided Vehicle program to do serial communication between Arduino and C# GUI application. after tweaking some user interface code and started to work on the serial communication, I stumbled with this problem.

while the Arduino sends multiple sensor data continuously without delay and each sensor's data were separated with newline, I couldn't get the job done to **read the full data and assign each of them to a different variable without missing text/string every 1 minute** using timer. from what I've understand is timer is a bad method to use because we wouldn't find the exact transfer speed in communication, that's why the data were only match in some times (5 out of 10 tries)

P.S. Maybe this problem seems easy for everyone here, but for the information, I'm new to C# and this is my first program so I might need a newbie-friendly guide to solve this.

currently im trying to get 4 data which is

1. Battery info
2. Proximity sensor
3. DC Motor Speed
4. DC Motor RPM
   from arduino into serialport read in C#, the data looks like this

```
00.0V, 00.0%, 000, CL
1,1,1,1
140,140
5,5
```

here's my code on getting the data with `ReadLine()` and splitting the data using `string[] result = XX.Split(',')` before assigning to different function to work later on.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s1, s2, s3, s4;
            s1 = sp.ReadLine();
            s2 = sp.ReadLine();
            s3 = sp.ReadLine();
            s4 = sp.ReadLine();

            string[] result_batt = s1.Split(',');
            string[] result_prox = s2.Split(',');
            string[] result_RPM = s3.Split(',');
            string[] result_speed = s4.Split(',');

            get_Batt(result_batt[0], result_batt[1], result_batt[2], result_batt[3]);
            get_prox(result_prox[0], result_prox[1], result_prox[2], result_prox[3]);
            get_RPM(result_RPM[0], result_RPM[1]);
            get_speed(result_speed[0], result_speed[1]);


            timer1.Start();
        }

private void get_Batt(string s0, string s1, string s2, string s3)
        {
            num = Regex.Replace(s1, "[%]", "");
            batt_val = Convert.ToInt32(num);

            progressBar1.Value = batt_val;
            if (batt_val <= 0)
            {
                label2.Text = "Working time remaining: Unknown";
                label3.Text = batt_val + "%";
            }
            else
            {
                label2.Text = "Working time remaining: xx:xx:xx";
                label3.Text = batt_val + "%";
            }

        }

        private void get_prox(string s0, string s1, string s2, string s3)
        {
            //mati
            label26.Text = s3;
            if (s3 == "0")
            {
                blackCircle4.Show();
                greenCircle8.Hide();
            }
            
            if (s0 == "0")
            {
                blackCircle1.Show();
                greenCircle5.Hide();
            }

            if(s1 == "0")
            {
                blackCircle2.Show();
                greenCircle6.Hide();
            }

            if(s2 == "0")
            {
                blackCircle3.Show();
                greenCircle7.Hide();
            }

            

            //nyala

            if (s0 == "1")
            {
                blackCircle5.Show();
                greenCircle1.Hide();
            }

            if (s1 == "1")
            {
                blackCircle6.Show();
                greenCircle2.Hide();
            }

            if (s2 == "1")
            {
                blackCircle7.Show();
                greenCircle3.Hide();
            }

            if (s3 == "1")
            {
                blackCircle8.Show();
                greenCircle4.Hide();
            }
        }

        private void get_RPM(string s0, string s1)
        {
            LRPM = s0 + " RPM";
            RRPM = s1 + " RPM";

            L_RPM.Text = LRPM;
            R_RPM.Text = RRPM;
        }

        private void get_speed(string s0, string s1)
        {
            LSpeed = s0;
            RSpeed = s1;

            L_Speed.Text = LSpeed;
            R_Speed.Text = RSpeed;
        }
```

after running my code, the result were oftenly different from what i desired, because of the timer function that affecting the first line to read depending on the serialport's data at given time (sometimes the program missed the starting point of the data and start to read from the middle-last block of the incoming data).

is there any possibilites of help and guide to make my project working?
any critics and suggestion would be highly appreciated

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to use timers to read, because that assumes your program is always perfectly synchronized with the sender. IOW if you expect to always read Line1, Line2, Line3, and Line4, then how do you recover from bad synchronization like getting Line3, Line4, Line1, Line2?

Comment: The better way to perform this is to continuously read a line, and then parse that line to determine its contents, i.e. whether it's battery, proximity, motor speed, or motor RPM  (what's the difference between motor speed vs RPM?). Instead of a timer simply use a blocking I/O. There' no reliance on sender-receiver synchronization. Lines can be sent in any order. Disconnects/reconnects and bad data are recoverable events.

Comment: Using a SerialPort, you have notifications when new data arrives. These notifications are provided in the form of events, which are generated in a ThreadPool Thread. You can elaborate the new data, store the results in a concurrent collection (e.g., ConcurrentBag), then use a Timer to read the last package that was sent and update the UI with this information, so you have no sync issues.

Comment: thank you @sawdust for your brief explanation about parsing the line to avoid bad order synchronization instead of reading each line with timer function which resulting a lot of uncertainty. I'll try it first and hopefully going to update my progress soon in my question thread here.

Comment: this is another way that I've been thinking for the past hour, thank you @Jimi for giving the insight about splitting the process from storing data and using timer as a function to read the last package that has been received instead and not directly use it to read the SerialPort